# Correctly escape a subcommand in a git alias

Tags: git

I would like to alias the following git command:

```
git commit --amend -m $(git log --format=%B -n1)
```

However if I add the following to my `.gitconfig` it errors with "error: unknown option `format=%B'"

```
[alias]
  amend = commit --amend -m $(git log --format=%B -n1)
```

Is there a way to have this command as an alias?  If I put the subcommand in single quotes it treats it like a string:

```
[alias]
  amend = commit --amend -m '$(git log --format=%B -n1)'
```

Running this using `git amend` results in the last commit being renamed to the literal: `$(git log --format=%B -n1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know almost nothing about `git` but I know `$( )` needs a shell that will interpret it. Usual git aliases are internal to `git`, they don't run any shell. To define a git alias that runs an arbitrary command you need `!`.

My tests indicate I don't need `!sh -c …` to make `git` run something in a shell. It seems the command after `!` is run in `sh` anyway. Note in `sh` `$( )` [should be double-quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Use this:

```
[alias]
        amend = !git commit --amend -m \"$(git log --format=%B -n1)\"
```

Double-quotes are escaped so (the outer) `git` does not use them up. You need them for the `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

[@Kamil Maciorowski's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1631758/148811) is correct but I just realised the functionality I wanted could be achieved by running:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Which can be aliased easily using:

```
[alias]
  amend = commit --amend --no-edit
```